# spray.json.JsonParser$ParsingException: Unexpected character '纲' at input index

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have to JSON objects. First one is

```
s"""
       |{
       |  "field1": "${value1}"
       |}
     """.stripMargin.parseJson
```

and

second one is

```
     JsObject(
        "field1" -> JsString(value1)
     )
```

Let `value1`  = "삭䋇뀉먹됉ޯ䡶柒濷걸笋࣐漭뫄茡", an unusual string.

First one throws an error 
`spray.json.JsonParser$ParsingException: Unexpected character '\u0017' at input index` but second one does not throw the error.

Are both of them different ?? I use `scala` language and `spray` JSON protocol

Comment: Scala 2.12.2 and spray 1.3.5

Comment: The error is thrown when assigning `val value1 = "\u0017"`

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the `spray-json` and parsing some unusual characters https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/178